# Infested with White Screen Virus?

Tags: virus, anti-virus, virus-removal

A few days ago my screen turned completly white and I was not able to do anything. I had to kill my PC with the power-button and restart it. Everything worked fine so I thought is was just some kind of system-crash.

But 5 minutes ago it happened again. I killed my PC again but it would not start for a few minutes. Only the fans started turning, but I could not even hear the high pitched sound  (which I think comes from the BIOS booting).

Now suddenly my PC was able to boot again and showed me this message in black on White while booting: "The Anti-Virus Software you have installed on your computer is now cleaning up.. Successfully done" (translated by me).

I googled a bit and found out there is ransomware going round that does exactly that. So may I be infested? 
Even this message that my anti-virus program is cleaning up sounded pretty suspicious..

Comment: If your system isn't even attempting to POST then it isn't a virus.  Doesn't mean it isn't both a hardware and a malware problem though

Comment: But the white screen in combination with that strange message?

Comment: Thanks for the link, but right now I am not really sure if im infected or not.

Comment: I simply indicated your failure to POST isn't cause by malware.  If ransomware broke your PC they would never be paid.  You have not even confirmed if your data is encrypted or not.